# filtering records in database

Tags: django, filter

I have a class '`material`' with a field

```
user = models.ForeignKey (User, default = 'request.user.pk')
```

I would like to not display all `records` in the `database` but only those related to a user

in '`url.py`' I wrote

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



   material_info = {"queryset": Material.objects.all ()}
```

and I get all the records of the database

but if I wanted those dependent of user login?

```
material_info = {"queryset": Material.objects.filter (user = User)}
```

does not work ..

Comment: Are you using django admin?

Comment: You might need to read the documentation better. You have several problems here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give my best stab at this but I don't think I fully understand the question.

You could filter the materials down to ones that relate to the user like this.

in a view...

```
material_info = Material.objects.filter(user=User)
```